# Using WHERE clause with csv files ADO.NET / C#

Tags: c#, csv, ado.net, oledb

i have a little problem. I'm using a csv file as database and i'm asking it with ADO.NET's OLEDB funcions.
I want to select only rows where column "DATA" is included between two datas, like this:

```
String conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\;
;Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;Format=Delimited(;)';";

OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(conn);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [mydb]", cn);
OleDbDataAdapter daAd = new OleDbDataAdapter();
daAd.SelectCommand= cmd;
cn.Open();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
daAd.Fill(dt);
DateTime mydata= Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1990");
DateTime mydata2= Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2000");
```

Nothing wrong until now, but when i change

```
 "SELECT * FROM [mydb]"
```

With

```
 "SELECT * FROM [mydb] WHERE DATA>= '"+ mydata.Date +"' AND DATA<='"+ mydata2.Date +"'
```

I have an error saying "Syntax error (missing operator) in query 'WHERE DATA=> mydata AND DATA<= mydata2'.
I really don't know how to solve it.
More info: .CSV file is formatted like this:

```
DATA;INFO1;INFO2;INFO3
01/01/1990;1;2;3`
```

And into schema.ini is this :

```
[mydb.csv]
Format=Delimited(;)
ColNameHeader=True
DateTimeFormat=dd-MM-yyyy
Col1=DATA DateTime
Col2=info1 Long Width 3
Col3=info2 Integer 
Col4=info3 Integer
```

**EDIT :**
I'm running a x86 Seven, i read that for solve JET driver's incompatibility is sufficient the schema.ini file, hope i'm right.

Comment: Don't you mean `>=` (not `=>`)?

Comment: Have you thought about using the BETWEEN key word in your query..I think you may get more accurate results

Comment: That my be useful, but the real problem is that it stops after the WHERE clause, i really don't know why

Comment: I think it could be down to your DateTimeFormat in you schema.ini... see my updated post below.

Comment: Tried that, but it doesn't solve the problem, i like it doesn't recognize the WHERE clause...

Comment: What is mydata and mydata2? How does the query know what values they are?

Comment: mydata and mydata2 are DateTime like "01/01/1990" and "01/01/1992", i pass them to query through variables ("where data<="+mydata+""), i'll add it to post for more clarity

Comment: Are you converting your variables to strings of the correct format? I'm just trying to think of all possibilities!

Comment: I pass them directly in DateTime format, using mydata.Date property

Comment: Are you escaping your values correctly, also make sure this is not vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: i don't escape variables in query,should I do it? 
But what's SQL injection? the possibility of being tracked and hacked? in that i don0't care, it's for personal uses and doesn't connect to the web in any case

Comment: @AnthonyStarkPirrone Typically dates in SQL must be quoted to be valid SQL.  `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyDate >= '2012-01-01'` is valid, where-as `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyDate >= 2012-01-01` means something else entirely.  Properly escaping your data in queries will also prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Need to send them as strings... see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of i'm quering a csv I can't use sql's functions(errors says they don't exist) not even compare my DATA with string. If i put in the query an unquoted date it works, but i don't respect the WHERE clause, selecting all records.
Query seems to doesn't work only for DateTime format, so i'll put my DATA in a yyyyMMdd Integer format.It's the only alternative I've in mind, still don't know why can't search with Datetime fields.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this:

```
SELECT * FROM [mydb] WHERE DATA=> mydata AND DATA<= mydata2
```

is clearly invalid SQL. Perhaps you meant:

```
SELECT * FROM [mydb] WHERE DATA>= mydata AND DATA<= mydata2
```

(You used `=>` for "greater than" rather than `>=`.)

Comment: Yeah, in my main code it's correct, i rewrite that so i mistakes, it's not that the error

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean this:

```
SELECT * FROM [mydb] WHERE DATA >= mydata AND DATA <= mydata2
```

You just got the => the wrong way round!

**UPDATE AFTER OP's CORRECTION**

Is it due to your schema.ini? You seem to have the wrong DateTimeFormat:

```
DateTimeFormat=dd-MM-yyyy
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
DateTimeFormat=dd/MM/yyyy
```

**SECOND UPDATE**

Change you mydata to the following:

```
"SELECT * FROM [mydb] WHERE DATA >= '" + 
    mydata.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + 
    "' AND DATA <= '" + mydata2.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'"
```

Comment: beacuase i was in a hurry when i post it,the main code is correct

Comment: Nothing changes. It can't fill the table beacuse of the same error

Comment: Sorry I can't think what else could be the issue. Looks good to me without setting up a project myself!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM [mydb] WHERE DATA >= mydata AND DATA <= mydata2
```

Note the order of "<" and "=" in the first comparison.